# Columns in subquery in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given temp tables that have been set up like this

```
select '1' a, '2' b into #tmp1
select '3' c, '4' d into #tmp2
```

Why doesn't the following give an error in SQL Server?

```
select * from #tmp1 where a not in (select b from #tmp2)
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to give and error?

Comment: @DVT Because `b` isn't a column in `#tmp2`

Comment: Columns from the main query are accessible in the subquery. So in the `select b from #tmp2`, the `b` is coming from `#tmp1`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan But is this ever what the user wants...? Especially in a column selected by a NOT IN subquery? I was terribly confused by this, especially since IntelliSense in Management Studio autocompleted column names like the `b` here.

Comment: I think Felix is right. It was just because this will give you error: "select * from #tmp1 where a not in (select e from #tmp2)"

Comment: @SveinFidjestøl The user might want this "select * from #tmp1 where a not in (select c from #tmp2 where c=b)".

Comment: @SveinFidjestøl It translate as "select * from #tmp1 where '1' not in ('2')" and that is a valid statement.

Comment: @DVT It's a valid statement, but it is clearly easy to make a mistake here which is hard to catch (which is why I'm asking this question). If not an error, a warning would have been nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no error because the columns from the main query are accessible in the subquery. So in

```
select b from #tmp2
```

the column `b` is coming from `#tmp1`.

[**Here**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178050(v=sql.105).aspx) is the article that explains it.

> If a column is referenced in a subquery that does not exist in the
>   table referenced by the subquery's FROM clause, but exists in a table
>   referenced by the outer query's FROM clause, the query executes
>   without error. SQL Server implicitly qualifies the column in the
>   subquery with the table name in the outer query.

Comment: It's easy to make mistakes here though, thinking one has entered a valid column name from #tmp2 in the subquery. I guess the lesson here is to always use aliases for tables and when selecting columns, like `select * from #tmp1 t1 where a not in (select t2.b from #tmp2 t2)`